# Android emulator shows empty space when it is running

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have coded a simple android application for get  some details from user.But when I run it in emulator ,it does not show any thing, only a white space. I use Android Studio 1.2.2 , Here I attached both design and text of xml file. Also the design view does not show inside a mobile interface.

This is my .xml file

```html
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".mainActivity.fragmentHolder">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="@string/label_new_claim_request"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_claim_request"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_official_no"
        android:text="@string/label_official_no"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText_official_no"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="#484848"
        android:hint="@string/label_official_no"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

  

    <Button
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="@string/button_create"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.83" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

```html
public class fragmentHolder extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_claim_request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the Solution. The Problem is in onCreate method. The onCreate method should be correct as follows.

```html
public class fragmentHolder extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_claim_request);
    }
  
}
```

Then it works fine.

Be sure, when you override onCreate method, that you select correct one or not. There are 2 onCreate method as onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){} and onCreate((Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)){}